# Escape the influence of flash elements in webpage using keyboard

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, adobe-flash

When watching a flash video in a browser (a youtube video in iceweasel, for example) if I interact with the flash element with a mouse, click to play or pause or something, the flash element seems to steal subsequent keyboard inputs meant for the browser.

Ctrl-tab, for instance, should cycle through open tabs, but when flash has stolen the focus it cycles through the control buttons of the video.  Or Crtl-w (close tab) and Ctrl-t (open tab) don't work.

I've found that the only way to get proper control back is to use the mouse to click anywhere except from the flash element.

Is there a way to overcome this behaviour?  I've noticed similar things happen on other web browsers and on other computers I've used, so I think it's a problem with flash and not a system-dependent problem.  I have a very keyboard-centric workflow and I find being forced to use the mouse by flash quite annoying.

Note, however, that other keyboard shortcuts that communicate with the desktop environment or window manager still work.

I hope this isn't completely the wrong place to ask this question, but if it is please direct me to anywhere you think would be more appropriate.

Thanks.

(I'm using two systems that show this problem.  Both Debian 8.0, with iceweasel, flashplugin-nonfree installed.  One runs xfce4, the other runs i3.)